# real path in windows azure website using PHP

Tags: php

I try to get real path in PHP

this is my code

```
<?php
    echo "\n1.". realpath('../testerror/warning.php');
    echo "\n2.". realpath('warning/warning.php');
    echo "\n3.". realpath('/testerror/warning.php'); 
?>
```

I get the result

```
1.D:\home\site\wwwroot\testerror\warning.php
2.D:\home\site\wwwroot\testerror\warning\warning.php
3.        ----> (I got nothing)
```

why i get nothing from code number 3

This is a problem because I need to include_once /testerror/warning.php from various location that's not necessarily the main directory.

Comment: the third one is already an absolute path in unix (starts with /) try './testerror/warning.php'

Comment: And that's the whole point. I want absolute path. It works in hostgator and many other hosts.

Answer (score 0):

do not use `realpath`, it is buggy. Try to use `__DIR__` and `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`

Comment: There are no warnings or message on the [manual page](http://php.net/realpath). How is it buggy?

Comment: @Phil Please read manual page carefully:5.3.0 - Prior to this release, if only the last path component did not exist, realpath() would not fail on *BSD systems. realpath() now fails in this case;
5.0.0 - Prior to this release, a blank or NULL path would cause realpath() to return the directory name of the script. Note: The running script must have executable permissions on all directories in the hierarchy, otherwise realpath() will return FALSE. Note: Because PHP's integer type ... some filesystem functions may return unexpected results for files which are larger than 2GB.

Comment: Your point being? 5.3.0 is the oldest supported version of PHP. It was released almost 5 years ago. You can't call a feature *buggy* if it was only *buggy* in a now unsupported version. In any case, those bugs refer to *BSD systems. OP is obviously using Windows

Comment: @Phil both of us has no idea which version @Jim is using. For lots companies they still run 5.0 or 5.2, as developer we just work with env, we play safe card. Even OP shows windows path, does not means it is same as deploy env. I do not make assumption, and I did have trouble with `realpath` before, I suggest since `__DIR__` and `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` can describe path more clealy, why choose something may bit you back?

Comment: @Phil besides, please also read the comments in the manual, it is not as reliable as __FILE__ or __DIR__.

Comment: `realpath` does an entirely different thing than `__FILE__` or `__DIR__`. It is a path **resolver**.

Comment: @Phil I agree, however, why ppl need path resolver for include their own php script code? Any programmer suppose to know script path before hand, and suppose to have base project path in init of the project script, that is the reason why you won't find solid php framework use it to load script files. Even spaghetti wordpress use `ABSPATH` instead of `realpath`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo "\n3.". realpath('./testerror/warning.php');
```

this is a path in Unix so it doesn't return any thing.